# TLC5955 Combining 48 outputs to 3 | PCB

Tags: power, led, pcb-design, led-driver, via

Can I combine the [TLC5955](https://www.ti.com/product/TLC5955) outputs in this way to connect one [350mA RGB LED](https://ru.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cree-Inc/MCE4CT-A2-0000-00A5AAAA1?qs=D3QG1iK7FqhzF0NlpmaAHg%3D%3D)? I calculated that **6 mil** at **1 oz Cu** would be enough for **32 mA**.

What thickness of PCB should I choose for heat removal from TLC5955 (32 mA * 48)? Probably need a radiator? I've never ordered a PCB, I made just a few simple single-layer PCBs myself. This is the first two-layer PCB with interlayer junctions - Vias. I installed EAGLE on the recommendation of PCBWay and drew this layout. PCBWay will print Via with a 0.3 mm hole and a ring around 0.5 mm for $5? I drew pairs of Via to avoid problems with metallization of the holes, I think this is a smart solution for delivering 32 mA from one layer to another.

Basically the led will glow red, so I chose direct connection for red, without Via. The blue one will have the least intensity, so I chose a long track with Via for it. I don't know how to draw polygons for the heat sink yet, so I've marked it this way for now. There is no connector for connection yet. I am open to opposition points of view.

[image: TLC5955 & 1 RGB LED]

[image: TLC5955 Pin out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Regulators need to explicitly designed to allow putting their outputs in parallel, and this is seldom done because the complexity of that is usually not worth it. You can see regulators like this mostly in computer mainboard designs with currents upwards of 100A.

To drive a 1A LED, use a single constant current regulator. The current is too high for linear regulators without elaborate cooling solutions, so a switching regulator is a way better idea here even if it needs a bit of stuff around it. Trace width should not be much of an issue there, but it is a good idea to use zones instead of traces nonetheless.

For manufacturing, use 2 oz copper thickness and either 1.6mm or 1mm PCB thickness. There's nothing wrong with others, but these are standard, so these will be cheap as your design can be combined with others for manufacturing (so the fab house will not make a huge PCB with ten copies of your design, but ten PCBs each containing ten customers' designs).

I've packed up an older project of mine, a [four channel 700mA LED driver](https://psi5.com/%7Egeier/led_driver.tar.gz), feel free to steal parts of the design. There will be a lot of impractical aspects for you like the connector that you need to change, and you might also want to separate the LED supply and the regulator supply (for which I use the same 5V rail). Each of the components I use is in the smallest possible package, so if you don't want to solder 0402, you can use 1206 or larger instead if you rearrange the board a bit, and you definitely need to change the value of the resistor setting the target current.

[image: rendering of LED driver board]

Comment: You are right, LT3476 has more power. I mean a 3.5W, max 7W [RGB LED](https://ru.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cree-Inc/MCE4CT-A2-0000-00A5AAAA1?qs=D3QG1iK7FqhzF0NlpmaAHg%3D%3D) and I chose TLC5955 because it has 65536 steps of brightness, and I need to smoothly change the brightness and color at the same time for a long time.

Comment: @Andre, the LT3476 doesn't have an internal PWM generator, so you'd connect an external PWM source with the desired resolution. 16 bits is rather fine, unless people are going to be looking directly into the LED (which they shouldn't), you can't really see the steps even with 8 bits.

Comment: @Andre, the LEDs you have are designed for 350mA per channel, not 1A.

Comment: More like reflected light, 8 bit is too noticeable and quite small for smooth transitions over 30 minutes.

Comment: @Andre, check if your microcontroller can do better than that then -- the Arduino libraries for example only allow 8 bit, while the hardware can do 10 directly, or use a timer for arbitrary fractions.

Comment: I will use the digital interface on nRF52 to control the built-in PWM in the LED Driver.

Comment: @Andre, the TLC5955 cannot drive these LEDs, because it can only sink 20mA per channel, and is not designed to have channels run in parallel, so you need a different driver IC. There might be high power driver ICs with built-in PWM, but likely not with good resolution.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, so I asked tech support in TI. Also, I found a [similar IC](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/p/802755/2972158#2972158) which supports connecting outputs to one.

Comment: [TLC5955 can't do this](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/p/939869/3472539)